# How to cancel a bias and analyse the data?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have a data table like this one, I would like to know which type of substrate (called "Litières" / "Branchages" / "Racines") contributes the most to each score.

in r :

```
Substrate<-c('Litières','Litières','Racines','Branchages','Branchages','Litières','Branchages','Litières','Litières' )

One<-c(0,22,216,36,288,351,28,12,0)

Two<-c(574,755,1248,504,882,810,431,537,56)

Three<-c(1352,1248,706,1476,846,855,1334,1152,1628)

Four<-c(261,162,17,171,171,171,394,486,503)

x<-data.frame(Substrate,One,Two,Three,Four)
```

or in a table :

| Substrate | One | Two | Three | Four |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Litières | 0 | 574 | 1352 | 261 |
| Litières | 22 | 755 | 1248 | 162 |
| Racines | 216 | 1248 | 706 | 17 |
| Branchages | 36 | 504 | 1476 | 171 |
| Branchages | 288 | 882 | 846 | 171 |
| Litières | 351 | 810 | 855 | 171 |
| Branchages | 28 | 431 | 1334 | 394 |
| Litières | 12 | 537 | 1152 | 486 |
| Litières | 0 | 56 | 1628 | 503 |

However you will notice that the number of substrate is not the same between each type of substrate. How to cancel this bias?

Thank !

Comment: Do you want to sum by group of substrate?

Comment: The result must be expressed in terms of the 3 types of substrates

Comment: Unequal replication of strata may not be a bias.  It may reflect reality.